# How to extract Latitude and Longitude of Shapefile for importing into Tableau?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, tableau

I'm having a hell of a time so any help would be appreciated.

I want to extract the latitude and longitude of the Health Authority boundaries from the zip file below.  The ultimate goal is to import these coordinates into Tableau.

http://www.bcstats.gov.bc.ca/Files/1d01fdf3-dc2a-4715-ba81-0aef150a49b8/Boundaries-HealthAuthorities.zip

Comment: Hi, you might want to consider posting the page where you downloaded the boundaries from ... not the zip file. I think quite a few people will be a little suspicious of clicking on a self extracting link!
Why do you need the coordinates in Tableau, what are you planning to do with them?

Comment: Is [**this**](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) the Tableau you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, it is for Tableau Software. The link for the shape files is under Health Boundaries: Health_Authorities
http://www.bcstats.gov.bc.ca/StatisticsBySubject/Geography/TranslationsDataSets.aspx I am wanting to try out the mapping function within Tableau so that is why I am trying to learn how to do so!

Comment: Are you looking for the coordinates of the vertices making up each polygon? the centroid? the extents?

Comment: I am guessing that I need the coordinates of the vertices making up each polygon. I have also reviewed "Creating Tableau Polygons from ArcGIS Shapefiles." I also tried to extract the coordinates via ArcGIS but it did not work! I had a trial version which did not allow me to import my own shape files!

Comment: GISnewbie, Please take a few moments to review our [faq] and learn how to manage comments and answers here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau has a knowledge base topic on this: [Creating Tableau Polygons from ArcGIS Shapefiles](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/tableau-polygons-arcgis-shapefiles).

The topic says to use ET GeoWizards tool to help prepare the shapefile, and that only free functionality from ET GeoWizards is needed. The Polygon-to-Point wizard is used, so you may be able to use the Geoprocessing tool, Feature to Point, if you have an ArcInfo license.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau can now connect to shapefiles natively, and import polygons.